# Opening an Express App (Nodejs) with Electron

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, electron

I have an application written in Express/Nodejs for backend, and angularjs (old, I know) for the front end. I am trying to open this application in an Electron window. I found a few things after searching and this is what I came up with.

main.js

```
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
require('./server/app.js')

function start() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600
  });

  mainWindow.loadURL(`http://127.0.0.1:8009/`);
  mainWindow.focus();

};

app.on('ready', start)
```

./server/app.js

```
var open = require('open');
var path = require('path')
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var api = require('./routes/api')();
var fs = require('fs')




var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../client'));




app.get('/api/getPoints/:instance', api.getPoints);
app.get('/api/startDataCollection/', api.startDataCollection);
app.get('/api/getEllipses/:instance', api.getEllipses);
app.get('/api/getOutliers/:instance', api.getOutliers);
app.get('/api/getLabels/:instance', api.getLabels);
app.get('/api/getDescription/', api.getDescription);
app.post('/api/postDescription/', api.postDescription);
app.post('/api/postLabel/', api.postLabel);
app.listen(8009, function () {
  console.log('Server listening at http://127.0.0.1:8009');

});
```

I start the server by requiring the app.js module. The app is coming up properly and I can access it at port 8009, but the electron window does not pop up.

Answer (score 0):

`app` is not a declared variable. You can try:

```
setTimeout(() => start(), 3000);
```

This will manually start the electron window after 3 seconds from Node startup.
If this works, export `app` from the module that you are requiring.

```
module.exports.app = app;
```